# Django ,How can I display account details when I select it?

Tags: django, checkbox, django-views

** for my problem, I find it very complex and I researched it a lot and did not find a solution. I hope for your support
I want when I choose the account, whether a parent or a child, to display it with the rest of its details on the other side of the template[![enter image description here][2]][2]
**

[image]

Comment: please your support @godd0t

Comment: @godd0t please your support